# Bad Alignment of TextView in a xml layout for Listview item in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have an xml layout for an item of Listview with 12 TextView elements.

They have no padding, no weight just an all margin of 2dp and are divided in three vertical linearlayouts of 4 TextViews.

In the 2nd vertical LinearLayout and in the second pair at the bottom I notice that the alignment on vertical is larger. Its something like the following **for a 4.5' inch screen** :

```
Text     Text     Text

aa       aa       aa 

Text              Text

aa       Text     aa
         aa
```

The xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/itemLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplayCC"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:hint="Text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtDD"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtDS"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:hint="Text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtDSP"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtDDC"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtDDP"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I have missed here?

Comment: i tested your code it works fine

Comment: I'd prefer it if you attached a screenshot rather. Also, isn't GridLayout better for this kind of thing?

Comment: GridLayout with LinearLayout or all GridLayout?

Comment: Just check if there are no extra white spaces at the end of second TextView in your second vertical LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Using dp(dip) unit is much better and easier and works for the most majer of screens